# $L^2$ bounds for the gradient of subsolutions to parabolic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

Suppose we have the differential inequality
$$
|\partial_t{u}+\Delta{u}|\leq C(|u|+|\nabla u|)
$$
in $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash B_R\times[0,1]$, where $B_R=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n,|x|\leq R\}$.  Then do we have that
$$
\||u|+|\nabla u|\|_{L^2(B_{3R}\backslash B_{2R}\times[0,\frac{1}{2}])}\leq C\|u\|_{L^\infty(B_{4R}\backslash B_{R}\times[0,1])}
$$ 
Maybe this is something standard, but I can't find a reference right now. So my question is how to prove such kind  of inequalites.

Thanks for any comment and reference.

Comment: For the elliptic case such inequalities can be found using integration by parts; for example if $|\Delta u| < C(|u| + |\nabla u|)$ then take the test function $\varphi = \eta^2|u|$ in the inequality $\int_{B_1} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi \leq C\int_{B_1}(|u| + |\nabla u|)\varphi$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz. (This is known as a Caccioppoli inequality). I would imagine the parabolic case is much the same, using parabolic cylinders instead of balls.